# Android app sometimes recreates the entire Activity on launch

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently working on a small project that uses `DataStore<Preferences>` to save some data. At seemingly random times, when I would uninstall and reinstall the app, I would get the exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are multiple DataStores active for the same file`

This is the relevant code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var appControllerSettings: AppControllerSettings

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            appControllerSettings = AppControllerSettings.getInstance(this@MainActivity)
        }
    }
}

class AppControllerSettings private constructor(context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val USERS_KEY = stringSetPreferencesKey("users")
        private val mutex = Mutex()
        private var instance: AppControllerSettings? = null

        /**
         * Return the singleton instance of [AppControllerSettings]
         * */
        suspend fun getInstance(context: Context): AppControllerSettings {
            return instance ?: mutex.withLock {
                instance ?: AppControllerSettings(context).apply {
                    try {
                        val preferences = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            preferencesStore.data.first()
                        }
                        val userIds: Set<String>? = preferences[USERS_KEY]
                        if (userIds != null) {
                            users.addAll(userIds)
                        }
                    } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                        debugError("failed to read app controller settings from preferences store", ioe)
                    }

                    instance = this
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private val preferencesStore = createPreferencesStoreFromFile(context, "app_controller_settings")
    private val users: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()

    suspend fun addUserToSignInHistory(user: User): Result<Unit> {
        return runCatching {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                preferencesStore.edit { preferences ->
                    users.add(user.id)
                    preferences[USERS_KEY] = users
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun hasUserPreviouslySignedIn(user: User): Boolean {
        return users.contains(user.id)
    }
}
```

I have tested the code and `getInstance` returns the same instance every time it is called in code, but the exception still occurs. After adding some logging statements I saw the difference between when there is a crash and when there is no crash:

#### Working

```
MainActivity class initialized
MainActivity object instance created
onCreate
AppControllerSettings.getInstance is called
AppControllerSettings class initialized
instance = null
PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create app_controller_settings
AppControllerSettings object instance created
onStart
onResume
```

#### Crashes

```
MainActivity class initialized
MainActivity object instance created
onCreate
AppControllerSettings.getInstance is called
AppControllerSettings class initialized
instance = null
PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create app_controller_settings
AppControllerSettings object instance created
onStart
onResume
onPause
onStop
onDestroy
MainActivity object instance created
onCreate
AppControllerSettings.getInstance is called
instance = null
onStart
onResume
PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create app_controller_settings
AppControllerSettings object instance created
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are multiple DataStores active for the same file
```

I have a couple of questions about this:

1. Why is the activity sometimes being created and destroyed and created again? No screen rotation is taking place. I have gone through the process of simply installing and uninstalling the app from ADB and Android Studio over and over again, and this behavior occurs about 1 in 4 times. A few minutes before I started to write this question, the MainActivity class itself was being reinitialized, not just a new object instance created, but that behavior has now suddenly stopped.
2. Even if a new MainActivity object is being created, how is the static field `instance` inside of `AppControllerSettings` being reset to null? It's a separate class in the same file.

## EDIT

This seems to at least answer question 2: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/singleton-with-object-declarations-gets-garbage-collected/4786/5 The `AppControllerSettings` class is only initialized when it's first used and is then a candidate for garbage collection if no reference is held to it anywhere than the `MainActivity` which is disposed of. The only solution seems to be to initialize `AppControllerSettings` in a custom `Application` class.

Comment: What does `createPreferencesStoreFromFile` look like?

Comment: @dominicoder

`fun createPreferencesStoreFromFile(context: Context, name: String): DataStore<Preferences> {
    return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create {
        context.preferencesDataStoreFile(name)
    }
}`

After further experimentation, everything works fine if I call `AppControllerSettings.getInstance` in my Application class. If I can get it to initialize outside of `MainActivity` there's no problems, as the singleton pattern works perfectly. The class will however get re-initialized if it's only called by `MainActivity`

Comment: If you use Dagger/Hilt, you can inject the application context and use the @Singleton tag when you provide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out why at some times my activity is being created, destroyed and created again while simply launching the app with no other changes, but I ended up resolving my problem via the singleton pattern.

As Android doesn't give you any mechanism by which to close a `DataStore`, once a `DataStore` is opened for a given file it remains open for the lifetime of the application.

The solution was to create a `DataStoreManager` like this:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.PreferenceDataStoreFactory
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStoreFile

interface DataStoreManager {

    companion object {

        private val LOCK = Any()

        private var instance: DataStoreManager? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): DataStoreManager {
            return instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = DataStoreManagerImpl(context)
                }
                instance!!
            }
        }
    }

    fun datastore(name: String): DataStore<Preferences>
}

private class DataStoreManagerImpl(private val context: Context) : DataStoreManager {

    private val datastores = mutableMapOf<String, DataStore<Preferences>>()

    override fun datastore(name: String): DataStore<Preferences> {
        return datastores.computeIfAbsent(name) {
            PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create {
                context.preferencesDataStoreFile(name)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and pass that into my AppControllerSettings like so:

```
class AppControllerSettings private constructor(dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager) {

    companion object {

        private val USERS_KEY = stringSetPreferencesKey("users")

        private val mutex = Mutex()

        private var instance: AppControllerSettings? = null

        /**
         * Return the singleton instance of [AppControllerSettings]
         * */
        suspend fun getInstance(dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager): AppControllerSettings {
            return instance ?: mutex.withLock {
                instance ?: AppControllerSettings(dataStoreManager).apply {
                    try {
                        val preferences = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            preferencesStore.data.first()
                        }
                        val userIds: Set<String>? = preferences[USERS_KEY]
                        if (userIds != null) {
                            users.addAll(userIds)
                        }
                    } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                        debugError("failed to read app controller settings from preferences store", ioe)
                    }

                    instance = this
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private val preferencesStore = dataStoreManager.datastore("app_controller")
    private val users: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()

    suspend fun addUserToSignInHistory(user: User): Result<Unit> {
        return runCatching {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                preferencesStore.edit { preferences ->
                    users.add(user.id)
                    preferences[USERS_KEY] = users
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun hasUserPreviouslySignedIn(user: User): Boolean {
        return users.contains(user.id)
    }
}
```

This way `dataStoreManager.datastore(String)` can be called many times, but only way DataStore will ever be created for a given name. Obvious in retrospect.